# R function output changes non-english (unicode) characters to nonsense

Tags: r, string, unicode

I´m writing a function in R that returns different strings based on the input, but it seems that any Swedish characters (åäö) gets garbled into nonsense when it gets returned from the function.

```
return_string<-function(x){

z<-switch(x,
        1 = c("<br><strong>åäö:</strong>"),
        2 = c("<br><strong>öäå:</strong>")
return(z)
}
```

but when i try to print it I get...

```
var<-1
z<-return_string(var) 
print(z)       
[1] "<br><strong>Ã¥Ã¤Ã¶:</strong>"
```

Which is strange as I have UTF-8 as default text encoding and I can use åäö just fine otherwise, it´s seems that it only happens when they get returned from a function in list or c() format. If I check Sys.getlocale I get...

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Swedish_Sweden.1252;LC_CTYPE=Swedish_Sweden.1252; 
LC_MONETARY=Swedish_Sweden.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Swedish_Sweden.1252"
```

And my Session info is...

```
    > sessionInfo()
    R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Swedish_Sweden.1252  LC_CTYPE=Swedish_Sweden.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Swedish_Sweden.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Swedish_Sweden.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tau_0.0-18         RColorBrewer_1.1-2 htmltools_0.2.6    magrittr_1.5      
[5] leaflet_1.0.0      shiny_0.12.2       sp_1.2-1          

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.2      lattice_0.20-33  digest_0.6.8     mime_0.4        
 [5] plyr_1.8.3       grid_3.2.2       R6_2.1.1         xtable_1.8-0    
 [9] jsonlite_0.9.17  scales_0.3.0     tools_3.2.2      htmlwidgets_0.5 
[13] munsell_0.4.2    httpuv_1.3.3     yaml_2.1.13      colorspace_1.2-6
```

Comment: There are a number of problems with the code you posted: (1) You can't name arguments 1 and 2, you have to use backticks if you do so (2) You're missing a close parenthesis. When I fixt hese two problems the code runs fine.

Comment: Same here. If I don't correct the mistakes pointed out by @SeñorO, I get a number of error messages when running the function definition. So, I cannot even run the code example that leads to the problem with the Swedish characters. If I correct the mistakes, everything runs fine. I don't have a Swedish locale.

Comment: Your locale does not look like UTF-8.

Comment: My bad on the syntax, I tried @42- second example and I still get the garbled output. After some more searching it seems it might be a bug [link](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2015-May/071252.html)  For those of you who get it to work, whats your sessioninfo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get an error when I attempt to run your code. The syntax of the alternatives for `switch` is different when the type argument is supposed to be `character` as your syntax appears to expect:

```
ret_str_chr <- function( type) {
   switch(type,
          '1' = c("<br><strong>åäö:</strong>"),
          '2' = c("<br><strong>öäå:</strong>") )
 }
 ret_str_chr(var)
#[1] "<br><strong>åäö:</strong>"
```

When the type/choice argument is numeric you only put the items to be returned in the order in which they would be indexed:

```
ret_str_n <- function( choice) {
   switch(choice,
          c("<br><strong>åäö:</strong>"),
          c("<br><strong>öäå:</strong>") )
 }

 var=1
 ret_str_n(var)
#[1] "<br><strong>åäö:</strong>"
```

Comment: My bad on the syntax, but when I try your second example I still get the garbled up output, It might be related to this bug [link](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2015-May/071252.html) what locale do you run on? Sorry for the short reply but the editing options for comments are horrid.

Comment: I'm using the 'en_US.UTF-8'-locale, but I'm not sure that you are using a UTF-8 locale. Your output says you are using a Windoze 1252-codepage. What does `l10n_info()` return?

Comment: It returns the following: $MBCS
[1] FALSE

$`UTF-8`
[1] FALSE

$`Latin-1`
[1] TRUE

$codepage
[1] 1252

.   But I worked around the issue by creating a csv file containing the various strings I want and read from that rather then storing them directly in the function, doing that gets me the proper output.

Comment: So I have answered your posed question as well as your unposed one?